# mysql - php - determine if two values are from same row

Tags: php, mysql

How would I get this done? Say for example if the user's first name is in the column called first name, and the last name is in the column called last name, how would I determine if these names are in the same row? Do I check using the id of the row? And increment? I'm not sure, now beginning php. Thanks.

Comment: How can they be in the same column, when they are seperated in first name and last name? EDIT: Nvm, just saw your edit on your post =)

Comment: You want to find if both the first and last name exist in the same row?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or MySQL. It's purely SQL

Answer (score 4):

By adding both values into a `where` condition combined with `and`

```
select * from your_table
where first_name = 'tom'
and last_name = 'sawyer'
```

It will return only records where both values are in the same row.